# Custom cast system to avoid slow dynamic_cast and qobject_cast

Tags: c++

I use Qt and i want my own casting system possibly to avoid `dynamic_cast` and `qobject_cast` in some situations, because they are slow (i already did some benchmark and my solution is much faster and has **O(1)** while `qobject_cast` and `dynamic_cast` have **O(N)**).

In situations where i have base class (`NApplicationElement` in this case) and every other class inherits from base class and another classes acting as interfaces, i need to quicky check if object is instance of specific interface.

So i choosed the pattern where the base class has methods `virtual Interface* to(Interface* inf) { return static_cast<Interface*>(nullptr); }` for every interface that exists in my model and if any subclass of base class implements that interface, it will override appropriate method of base class. I use macros for simplicity.

`H_DEF_INTERFACE` and `CPP_DEF_INTERFACE` are used in base class to declare and define those default `to` methods. `H_USE_INTERFACE` and `CPP_USE_INTERFACE` are used by subclasses and interfaces (they just override `to` methods from base class).

Than there is this macro `CPP_INTERFACE`, which causes the error below. This macro is used in constructor initializer list to initialize interfaces with pointer to instance of base class, which i need to support casting FROM interface. Without it it will be possible to cast only TO interface. You can see i am trying to initialize the interface `inf`
with value returned by base class method `to(NApplicationElement*)`. However i get that weird error below. Does anyone see why it happened?
I cast that `nullptr` because i want force the compiler to call right method because of method overloading.

```
 #define CPP_INTERFACE(inf) inf(to(static_cast<NApplicationElement*>(nullptr)))
```

**error: invalid conversion from 'NApplicationElement*' to 'NCustomElement*' [-fpermissive]**

```cpp
#ifndef INTERFACE
#define INTERFACE

// this is just to try how much is the qobject_cast sensitive to class name length
//#define NApplicationElement Aasfasfasfasfasfsasafasfasfa
//#define NWindow Basfasfasfasfasfasfasfsafas
//#define NCustomElement Casfasfasfasfasfasfasfasf

#define N_CAST
//#define Q_CAST
//#define CPP_CAST

template <typename T, typename D>
T ncast(D obj) {
    return obj->to(static_cast<T>(nullptr));
}

#define H_INTERFACE(ifn) public ifn
// this previous version using only macros needs to be reworked using template to support
// cast from interface
//#define CPP_INTERFACE(inf) inf(toNApplicationElement())
//#define H_USE_INTERFACE(inf) virtual inf* to##inf() /* Q_DECL_OVERRIDE */;
//#define CPP_USE_INTERFACE(clazz, inf) inf* clazz::to##inf() { return static_cast<inf*>(this); }
//#define H_DEF_INTERFACE(inf) virtual inf* to##inf();
//#define CPP_DEF_INTERFACE(clazz, inf) inf* clazz::to##inf() { return nullptr; }

#define CPP_INTERFACE(inf) inf(to(static_cast<NApplicationElement*>(nullptr)))
#define H_USE_INTERFACE(inf) virtual inf* to(inf* t) /* Q_DECL_OVERRIDE */;
#define CPP_USE_INTERFACE(clazz, inf) inf* clazz::to(inf* t) { return static_cast<inf*>(this); }
#define H_DEF_INTERFACE(inf) virtual inf* to(inf* t);
#define CPP_DEF_INTERFACE(clazz, inf) inf* clazz::to(inf* t) { return nullptr; }

#if defined(N_CAST)

#define CAST(obj, clazz) ncast<clazz*, decltype(obj)>(obj)
// previous version using only macros (will not work for casting from interface)
//#define CAST(obj, clazz) (obj->to##clazz())

#elif defined(Q_CAST)

#define CAST(obj, inf) (qobject_cast<inf*>(obj))

#else

#define CAST(obj, inf) (dynamic_cast<inf*>(obj))

#endif

#define INTERFACE_CONSTRUCTOR(inf) inf(NApplicationElement* upcast) : NModelInterface(upcast) { }

class NApplicationElement;

// every interface needs to inherit from this so we can than somehow to use the m_upcast for casting
// from interface
class NModelInterface
{
    NApplicationElement* m_upcast;
public:
    NModelInterface(NApplicationElement* upcast) { m_upcast = upcast; }

};

#endif // INTERFACE
```

Comment: Because the compiler can't see the definition of `NApplicationElement*` because it wasn't included in this file?

Comment: @immibis: no probably not, i have this file included in napplicationelement.h and using only napplicationelement.h

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (preferably after preprocessing) .  `NCustomElement` is not mentioned in your code.

Comment: Please don't edit solutions into the question. Instead, post an Answer in the answer box and you can accept your own answer

Answer (score 0):

So i found the solution. In the constructor initializer list where the interface is initialized with pointer to instance of base class, the call to `to(NApplicationElement*)` method of base class needs to be qualified with base class name. Not sure why it doesn't work otherwiese. The line with error needs to be as below:

```
#define CPP_INTERFACE(inf)inf(NApplicationElement::to(static_cast<NApplicationElement*>(nullptr)))
```